# Printing to an Epson Stylus SX420W from macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, printing, driver

I was out of ink, and borrowed my neighbours Epson Stylus SX420W (the box says SX425W, but it identifies as SX420W on my iMac), but I can't print to it, and don't find a suitable driver. The printer is a couple of years old and connects via USB.

According to [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201465#epson) the drivers for this printer model should be included with macOS Sierra.

When I open the Printers & Scanners preferences, hit the + to add a new printer and select the Epson Stylus SX420W in the list, the dialog tells me the drivers for this printer model is *not available* from Apple. Which clearly contradicts the page above...

When I go to the [Epson Europe support page for the printer](http://esupport.epson-europe.com/ProductHome.aspx?lng=en-GB&data=0ccCGROWIYPeNJVkNLhQ4eUeedek5jbPbdPwLvz9g2AU003D&tc=6), I find only drivers for the scanner part of the device. No printer driver.

Does anyone know ho to set up this printer correctly on an iMac running macOS Sierra?

*Update:* I later returned the printer to my neighbour, and he helped me print my documents *from his MacBook Pro*. He couldn't recall having installed any extra printer drivers, but as we were both in a hurry, we didn't investigate further. I believe he was running Yosemite or El Capitan.

(Sorry for the inaccurate language, my <strike>OS X</strike> macOS installation is in Norwegian)

Comment: I wonder if those drivers are an *optional* part of the install. EG try reinstalling the OS, click on the customize button and see if there is an option for additional printer drivers. Not sure tho, it's been a while...

Comment: Just to clarify, can other computers print to this printer and only you can't?

Comment: @fsb Yes, see my update above.